# Kinetic energy of a mixture of gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Considering (in kinetic theory), supposed that there's a mixture of gas which doesn't interact with each other.  Let's consider the mixture is hydrogen and deuterium.

It is known that the system is in equilibrium.

If we look at deuterium and hydrogen separately, do they both have the same average kinetic energy and do both of them individually follow Maxwellian distribution?

Comment: I apologize, but this seems homework-like to me. So how can a single system that does not interact be in equilibrium? When you look at the Maxwell distribution, and plug in the numbers yourself, what results do you get?

Comment: @Countto10 Firstly, no it's not homework, I'm thinking about it myself. When I say they do not interact, I mean that the particles have no inter-molecular forces.

Comment: @Countto10 Perhaps the fact that I didn't make what I meant by "does not interact" clear enough proves that it is not a homework question.

Comment: Gases converge to a single thermodynamic temperature only when they interact with each other, typically through binary particle collisions.  Gases can have the same thermal speeds but not the same temperatures as well (i.e., if different mass for each constituent gas) but again, this will only last as long as the energy dissipation mechanisms allow it (e.g., in a highly collisional gas this will not last long).